# Windows .Bat file behave differently when executed from command window and by double clicking on the bat file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, services, double-click

batchfile is simple which has only two lines below, but behaves differently.

run from command window.

```
> sc \\server query | findstr SERVICE_NAME | find /c /v ""      //result is 135
> sc query | findstr SERVICE_NAME | find /c /v ""               //result is 135
```

run from double clicking.

```
> sc \\server query | findstr SERVICE_NAME | find /c /v ""      //result is 15
> sc query | findstr SERVICE_NAME | find /c /v ""               //result is 15
```

in this case, a lot of services are dropped.

what is the reason of this?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your cmd window is run with administrative privileges, but when you double-click the script, you don't run it with administrative privileges.

If you right-click the script and choose Run as Administrator, I suspect the output will be the same.

Comment: If I run it as Adminstatror, its result is same.  a lot of services are missing. for your referece, to login my PC, I use AD accounts. Is it related?

Comment: Can you rename the file from .bat to .cmd and see if that solves it? .bat uses an old interpreter set where .cmd uses a modern one.

Comment: I changed the extension vice versa. It is same.

Comment: And you're not using Windows Terminal by any chance, or Powershell?

Comment: I use Windows Terminal by manual,. When double clicking batchfile, it also run from it.

Comment: I guess my question is related with http://craig.dubculture.co.nz/blog/2007/12/07/querying-the-status-of-a-windows-service/, however I am not fully understand.

Comment: `<con: %ComSpec% /c "sc \\server query | findstr SERVICE_NAME | find /c /v """`